# Google Map API v3 - map.fitBounds(bounds) causes Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API V3, plotting markers from an array.  I am trying to center and zoom to the markers.  The problem I am having is that as soon as I try to use this line:

`map.fitBounds(bounds);`

I get this error:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

When I comment-out the fitBounds line, everything works fine and the markers are plotted, although the map is not centered and zoomed correctly.  Is there something wrong with the way that I have structured this code that might be causing the error?

```
function setMarkers(map, data) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var salecomp = data[i];
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);               
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng, 
    map: map, 
    title:data.address });          
  bounds.extend(myLatLng);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds); // THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE ERROR
}
```

When I alert the value of `bounds`, it appears that one of the latitude or longitude values may be null.  Could this be the reason for the error?

[image: value of bounds]

Comment: How many markers are you creating?  Do any of them have incorrect values for their latitude or longitude (e.g. out of the normal ranges)?

Comment: what is the value of bounds when you call map.fitBounds?

Comment: Thanks @duncan and @geocodezip.  I am only creating about 50 markers.  I have edited the question to show the value of `bounds`, it appears that at least one of the lat lon values is null. Maybe this is the source of the error?

Comment: almost certainly.  Eliminate that marker(s) from your data and test again.  If this is a likely scenario you probably need some error checking before creating each marker.

Comment: Thanks @duncan, you were right.  Once I filtered out the records with incomplete or missing lat lon values, the error went away.  Really appreciate your help.  Cheers.

Comment: A note to others: Make sure that you're passing around the entire object returned by `new google.maps.LatLng()`. I made the mistake of trying to access it's properties directly to get the lat/long (using `myLatLng.k` and `myLatLng.D`) and  those properties suddenly changed on my live site, (to `myLatLng.A` and `myLatLng.F`.)